# Does iLivid actually host files?

Tags: file-sharing

Accessing a number of file sharing websites in the past week led me ending up on ilivid (specifically, http://lp.ilivid.com/... ), which prompted me an executable payload, instead of the file I'm actually looking for.

Downloading the payload to a virtual machine, and poking around in their "Download Manager" yielded no results in actually reaching the file I'm looking for. It seems like a standard youtube video downloader, with a truckload of upsales to browser extensions / etc.

Yet, they seem to have an Alexa rank of 239 ( http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/ilivid.com#  )

I notice, that I am confused.

Questions:

- Does iLivid actually facilitate access to files otherwise inaccessible via a web browser?
- If not, what is it used for? What purpose do they serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of the site is to get people to download programs bundled with adware/spyware/malware etc.

There are plenty of user submitted ratings of the site on Web of Trust: http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/lp.ilivid.com

I would think they got their impressive Alexa ranking through browser exploits from people that downloaded files from their site. I would avoid this site completely.

Hope this helps ;)